# building static library (.lib) VS 2010 Pro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I have a newbie question about building a static library in VS 2010 Pro.

When you choose to build a static library (.lib) instead of an application, the Linker option in project properties disappears. Normally I go to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies to add the needed .lib files for a project.

I've built the library and added it to my main application project under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. Now when I go to build my main application (with the above static library included in the project .lib files), I am getting a linker error about a method used in the library.

Where do I add the required .lib files when building the static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Static library is linked with your executable.  Any dependencies that your static library has (external libraries it requires) must *also* be specified in your executable.

So, if `libA` requires `libB`, then an application that links with `libA` will also have to link with `libB`.

Comment: Darn. That's annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the dependent .lib to your main application in its linker page.

Answer (score 0):

If library A always depends on library B, then you can force that to happen in one of the source files in library A. For example:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
```